# make a certain URL valid only for 48 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a need to make a certain URL valid only for 48 hours, This link is generated on the server and sent to the client via email.

What I thought of doing is embedding a encoded time stamp on the server.

- This time stamp of course needs to be encoded, how ever I don't want my client side to have decoding capabilities.
- Another  thought is using a public encryption where the key is the user name

What are the best practices for this scenario?

Comment: When the URL expires, what would happen? You would return a 404 on the server if a user tried accessing the URL? You can't make the URL disappear from the e-mail, so I guess those are your options, so no need to worry about decrypting anything on the client-side.

Comment: The answer will largely be determined by the behaviour of the URL outside the time period: what should happen when the URL is visited at another time?

Comment: your first option looks great. create a file handler, append the time-stamp to the url and serve the file only when it is valid otherwise 404. many secure file sharing service use the same concept. some use it to limit the time, some for ip some for cache/versioning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would store the link in a database with an Id and an expiration date. When the user visits the link, I'll cross check the expiration date and see if it's expired.

Answer (score 6):

*This implementation is not secure to use, see my note below.*

If you'd like to implement your check like @craig1231 suggested who uses your idea to "encode" a timestamp, you can use code like this:

```
private const string SECRET = "secret of your choice";

private string getSHA1Hash(string strToHash)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1Obj = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] bytesToHash = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strToHash);
    bytesToHash = sha1Obj.ComputeHash(bytesToHash);
    string strResult = "";
    foreach (byte b in bytesToHash)
    {
        strResult += b.ToString("x2");
    }
    return strResult.ToLower();
}

public bool IsValidRequest(long expiryTicks, string hash)
{
    var expired = new DateTime(expiryTicks);
    var toHash = expiryTicks + SECRET;
    if (expired < DateTime.Now)
        return false;
    if (hash.ToLower() == getSHA1Hash(toHash))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public string GetHashForExpiryTicks(long expiryTicks)
{
    var toHash = expiryTicks + SECRET;
    return getSHA1Hash(toHash);
}
```

To generate a link you can get your hash parameter like this

```
var hash = GetHashForExpiryTicks(DateTime.Now.AddHours(48).Ticks);
```

**Edit 2022**: Note that this is an at least suboptimal if not insecure implementation, given this a) uses SHA1 and b) does not do proper message signing. A valid implementation would sign the expiry timestamp using a proper message signing algorithm like [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). For an example how to sign and verify using C# and HMAC that is secure (as of 2022-01), see for example Microsoft's [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=net-6.0). Note that the example signs a file and demonstartes the relevant concepts but is not as specific to the original question as my outdated above answer was.

Comment: shouldn't it be:
    expiried < DateTime.Now

Comment: How validate the request URL full source code sample ? `IsValidRequest(????, ????` ?

Answer (score 2):

The way Amazon S3 does it is to have an expiry and a hashed parameter...

http://www.myurl.com/index.php?expire=1409140600&hash=3984cfabc

So the hashed parameter validates the URL, and the expiry parameter validates the date

Comment: How generate the url, and how validate the url ?

Answer (score 1):

you've option to store the link and time of its creation in database. when user request that link, compare the time of creation with current time and if it is less than two days then full fill the request otherwise show some error message and delete the link from database :)